# Translating a UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I would like to ask is it possible to translate the UIButton position?

How? Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the frame of the button using "frame" property. This returns a CGRect object which basically has your buttons x-coord, y-coord, width and height.

Based on where you want to translate your button, calculate the new x-coord and y-coord.
Then do the following:

```
btnMyButton.frame = CGRectMake(oldx,oldy,width,height);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:btnMyButton];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];  
btnMyButton.frame = CGRectMake(newx, newy, width, height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```