# UISegmented Control Animation / Translation

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uisegmentedcontrol, uianimation

I am trying to translate a Segmented Control Vertically when index 0 is pressed, so that a 
UITextView can appear in it's position. I have the animation for the UITextView working.

I have tried to implement the following code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613306/translating-a-uibutton) other stackoverflow thread. With btnMyButton being replaced with 
mySegControl.

```
btnMyButton.frame = CGRectMake(oldx,oldy,width,height);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:btnMyButton];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];  
btnMyButton.frame = CGRectMake(newx, newy, width, height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

When changed, the
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone      forView:presentingComplaintSegCtrl];

Gives the following warning:
"Semantic Issue
 Class method '+setAnimationTransition:forView:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"

Is there a better way to approach this?

Note: I am creating the Segmented Control in the XIB.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning says, the method '+setAnimationTransition:forView:' doesn't exist in UIView. The method you are looking for is '[+setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationTransition%3aforView%3acache%3a)'. However, in the documentation there is a note that says:

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the [transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView%3aduration%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a) method to perform transitions instead.

If you don't need to support iOS 3.x, I would advise you to do as Apple says and use the method 'transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:' for your animation :)

**[EDIT]**

Hey @Ríomhaire, reading your question again... for your example it's probably best if you just use the [animateWithDuration:animations:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3a) method in UIView. Write the code for the changes that you want to animate inside a block and pass it as a parameter to this method. Here is some documentation about blocks in case you need it: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html

Comment: Thank you palpoms for your speedy reply.

Comment: Thank you palpoms and @Justin-Paulson for your speedy reply. I Attempted to use both, but I lack the understanding to perform correct execution. I am also new to stackoverflow, so please excuse any poor etiquette. If you have the time could you please show me an example of show to use the preferred function? If not, not to worry, thank you for pointing me in the correct direction.

Comment: Hi Ríomhaire, did you read the example in the documentation? It's in the discussion of the method [transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView%3aduration%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a)

Comment: Yes I did, unfortunately it went over my head as I am new to iOS development. My code for the transition is inside of a UIScrollView, so I am not sure if the UIScrollView is the container view, or something else? I think I understand the UIViewAnimationOptions, as I have used it before successfully. However, I am also unsure as to how the "animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion" fits in with my above mentioned code. I know I am a out of my depth here, but I figured I would learn a lot from it.

Comment: Hi Guys, I got the +setAnimationTransition:forView:cache: method working, it turns out that I did not have the IBOutlet for mySegmentedControl hooked up. So that's brilliant. Thanks. I'm going to move on to attempted the preferred method now. :)

Comment: Hey @Ríomhaire, reading your question again... for your example it's probably best if you just use the [animateWithDuration:animations:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:) method in UIView. Write the code for the changes that you want to animate inside a block and pass it as a parameter to this method. [Here is some documentation about blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html).

Comment: I have now edited my answer to add the info from my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `+setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:`

From the reference for UIView:

> cache If YES, the before and after images of view are rendered once
>   and used to create the frames in the animation. Caching can improve
>   performance but if you set this parameter to YES, you must not update
>   the view or its subviews during the transition. Updating the view and
>   its subviews may interfere with the caching behaviors and cause the
>   view contents to be rendered incorrectly (or in the wrong location)
>   during the animation. You must wait until the transition ends to
>   update the view. If NO, the view and its contents must be updated for
>   each frame of the transition animation, which may noticeably affect
>   the frame rate.

so add `cache:YES` or `cache:NO`

or, as palpoms mentioned as I typed this, use `transitionWithView:...`